# Get number of RSS Subscribers for a website

Tags: php, rss, blogs

I need to get the number of rss subscribers for a website. Say http://blog.twitter.com. How do I do that in PHP? Please help thanks. Google RSS subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Just tracking the calls to your rss feed via PHP will not give you accurate results as google reader (or other webbased services) ges the feed only once for all subscribers.

You can use an external Service like Feedburner (feedburner.google.com) which gives you subscriber metrics. You basically just proxy your feed through their system.